# Is there a way to get a non-node result from MSXML XPath evaluator?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, msxml

I understand that the name of selectNode/selectSingleNode methods actually suggests that they are designed to return a node, however maybe there is some other way or a setting available to enable XPath evaluator to return data of other types (that are also valid XPath results)

```
oDocument.selectSingleNode("'1'");
```

throws an error "Expression does not return a DOM node"

I want to query oDocument.selectSingleNode("concat(@day, '-', @month, '-', @year") and get a result (that is possible with standard DOM XPath API). Indeed I can query for nodes and then traverse them with DOM, however this would be way to inefficient.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? Maybe another way exists?

Comment: I want to query oDocument.selectSingleNode("concat(@day, '-', @month, '-', @year") and get a result (that is possible with standard DOM XPath API). Indeed I can query for nodes and then traverse them with DOM, however this would be way to inefficient.

Comment: but "oDocument.selectSingleNode("concat(@day, '-', @month, '-', @year")" implies a context node - where should it come from? Which node's attributes do you refer to? I can hardly imagine there is any selectSingleNode implementation that actually does what you try here.

Comment: Tomalak, you are a smart guy, indeed you understand what am doing. imagine the call is done on Element node: oElement.selectSingleNode("concat(@day, '-', @month, '-', @year")

Comment: "concat(@day, '-', @month, '-', @year)" does return a string, and not a node list, end of story, as far as SelectSingleNode() is concerned. Try selectNodes("(@day | @month | @year)") and concat them in the calling application.

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure if the smirk in your comment is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectSingleNode()` and `selectNodes()` select nodes identified by an XPath expression.

Their return values are of type `IXMLDOMNode` and `IXMLDOMNodeList`, respectively. Nothing else can be returned.

Expressions that do not return a node set (but otherwise are valid XPath expressions) will result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

**The API exposed by msxml do not allow this**.

**You may look into [the source code](http://www.topxml.com/code/cod-422_10119_xpath-visualizer-14.aspx) of the [XPath Visualizer](http://www.topxml.com/code/cod-422_10119_xpath-visualizer-14.aspx) to see how such XPath expressions are successfully evaluated**. Just in few words, when an exception is caught attempting to evaluate an XPath expression, and this exception's message is exactly the one provided in your (original) question, then a special XSLT transformation is created dynamically, and it returns the result of the XPath expression using `<xsl:value-of>`